# How to change a PSIClass object in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to change the text on a PsiClass object in IntelliJ (correspondent to a .java file) but there is only a getText() method and not a setText() one. How can I do that ? Do I need to create a new PsiClass object?

Here is the code:

```
        // Translation will be made here
    Processor<PsiClass> processor = new Processor<PsiClass>() {
        @Override
        public boolean process(PsiClass psiClass) {
            // Do work here
            System.out.println(psiClass.getText());
            return true;
        }
    };

    // Get all JavaClasses on project folder
    AllClassesGetter.processJavaClasses(
            new PlainPrefixMatcher(""),
            project,
            GlobalSearchScope.projectScope(project),
            processor
    );
```

Comment: What transformation do you need to perform? Normally transforming the class as a whole is not a correct way to perform an operation; it's better to use more localized transformations.

Comment: I need to change the file's text like changing a certain method's name or a variable name. Essentially I want to perform string manipulation on each class Object.

Comment: In an IDE, you can do much better than string manipulation; you have a full object model that provides a semantic API for most operations. E.g. changing the name of a method is done via `PsiMethod.setName()`.

Comment: So what I need to do is to check all PsiMethods on a certain PsiClass, for example? With that, can I also edit their bodies ?